# Why are the numbers of Logia and Zoan Devil Fruit users lower when compared to Paramecia users?

Tags: one-piece

From the [wikia:](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit)

```
                    Canon   Non-Canon   SBS
Paramecia -          49*       15        2
Zoan -               17         3        0
Logia -              11         3        0
Unspecified -         0         1        1
Total Devil Fruits - 77*       22        3
```

It is clear that Paramecia users outnumber both Zoan and Logia users. Is there any specific reason for that?

I think that more Zoan users mean more animals, so it will have less creativity (for attacks) compared to other Devil Fruits. So that may be a reason for less Zoan users till now.

But what about Logia? Most Logia users are big-shots.

Comment: 101 Devil Fruit users (including unnamed) seemed only a little, but it seems that Oda only slowly introduced them, but after entering the Grandline more are introduced at a faster pace. He introduced 2 fruits in '97, 1 in '98, 4 in '99, 13 in '00, 0 in '01, 5 in '02, 1 in '03, 3 in '04, 1 in '05, 6 in '06, 6 in '07, 12 in '08, 17 in '09, 2 in '10, 1 in '11, 9 in '12, 12 in '13, 5 in '14 and 1 in '15.

Comment: The answer is because Oda chose it to be this way.  He could have Zoan be far more common (there are quite a few more than 49 animals in the world) but chose this to be the way the world works. As to why he chose that... that is why this is a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is pretty simple. Logia Devil Fruits give you the power to become an element, Zoan fruits give you the power to become an animal, Paramecia fruits are those which allow you to do anything else.

Imagine if you divided all cars you saw into Volvos, Peugeots, and Others. You'd expect far more of the third category because it's definition is broader. So out of all the Devil Fruits in existence, you'd expect more to be Paramecia than others.

I think Logia should be even more under reported than they are, as they are stated to be the rarest and most powerful of the three types of fruit, but at the Whitebeard War, many of the most powerful men in the world were shown, so the fruits we've seen are skewed towards the more powerful.

Comment: Just wait until Kaido shows up and Zoan will skyrocket!

Comment: @PeterRaeves But kaido uses artificial devil fruit.So will it count?

Comment: @userXtreme You would end up having 4 categories, namely Volvos, Peugots, Landwinds and Others or something, but depending on how many Oda introduces, you might need to change your reply if he introduces thousands lol.

Comment: But if you look at the Zoan wikia page, they will just put artificial zoans with regular zoans, since [Momonosuke face is put together with the other Zoans](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Zoan#Users)

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Qiri's answer, [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_35#Chapter_334.2C_Page_146) is the SBS where Oda basically mentioned the same Qiri did.

> **Reader**: Oda-sensei, I was curious; is Foxy the Silver Fox's Noro Noro no Mi a Logia type, Paramecia type, or Zoan type? I'll be too anxious for your reply to use the bathroom, so hurry it up.
>
> **Oda**: It's a Paramecia (superhuman) type. Logia (nature) type can turn their bodies into something completely different. Zoan (animal) type can turn into animals. **Everything aside from those is lumped into the Paramecia (superhuman) category.** However, there are some Paramecia who can change their own bodies, as well.

Oda indeed confirms that Logia and Zoan are a specific Devil Fruit, but everything else would be considered *superhuman* and is lumped into that category, so it would make sense for it to be the largest category.